# Laravel Lumen 5.2 Cors Middleware not working

Tags: laravel, header, cors, lumen, lumen-5.2

In Laravel Lumen 5.1 i am using this in my CorsMiddleware:

```
public function handle($request, \Closure $next)
{
    $response = $next($request);
    $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers',  $request->header('Access-Control-Request-Headers'));
    $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    return $response;
}
```

But in 5.2 its not working anymore.

How do i return the appropriate headers in the response?

Answer (score 1):

Put all your routes inside to enable web middleware group:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    // Here comes your routes
});
```

**Upd.**

To resolve this, please use this package: [github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors)

Comment: Headers are still missing

Comment: Could you please add more information to your question? Like routes file? Or you can simply use this package: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors

Answer (score 1):

Browsers use `OPTIONS` requests to check if you have any CORS headers on your endpoint. Which means, that you need to care of those pre-flight OPTIONS requests first, providing them with correct headers.

In Lumen/Laravel you need to add your CORS middleware also to the same route as your CORS resource, but requested with OPTIONS method:

```
$app->options(
    'your/cors/uri',
    [
        'middleware' => 'cors', function() 
         function() { return response('', 200); }
    ]
);
```

Had the same problem, so I hope that this helps you :)